# Django - possible for users to overwrite variable in memory?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

If I have list stored as a class variable that receives items throughout the course of a session, is it possible that multiple users in my Django application could be writing/overwriting the same variable in memory?

Comment: Yes. Using a mutable class variable is almost always wrong. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes pretty much if you have allowed or exposed  any methods to perform these changes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I'm taking over a website developed by someone else and wanted to confirm that this was an anti-pattern. They are basically using the class variable as a collector for all instances of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should not do this.

You hinted at the correct answer in your question: you should use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/) to store per-user information between requests.